# Video tag in Html5, android

Tags: android, html

Is it possible to play a remote video which is in server using html5 in android.
I have tried playing the local video and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Android  tag support is very flanky in currently deployed phones. You can search about various problems of it here at stackoverflow.com.

I'd suggest using    link to a video file on the remote server which is then opened in a standalone media player. This guarantees that the video will work on all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

works fine in 2.3+ (tested personally on 2.3, 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2)

try absolute paths instead of relative paths, the type attribute should only read "video/mp4" or "video/webm" - nothing more!

check http://caniuse.com/webm and http://caniuse.com/mpeg4 for supported codecs. Ogg-Video is not supported so far.